# facing problem in creating npm package of vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, npm-install

I have to create an package of vue component and then install it in another project. 
My code sample is given [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-1k47n). After using **npm run build command** I got a converted js file. 
I install it in another project. And in my project in main.js, I am using below line to add this dependency.

```
 import 'test'
```

but in my browser I am getting this error.

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the
>   component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
>   the "name" option.
>
> (found in )

I dont understand what I am missing for adding **funnel** component to my project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to also declare in the `components` option.

```
import test from 'test

export default {
  components: {
    test
  }
}
```